# Storing and retrieving unique random values for each customer and each order separately in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a product in `WooCommerce` that generates random unique strings (or values) at the time of purchase by the customer. This product can be purchased multiple times by the customer or multiple copies can be purchased at the same time.

**I am facing a few challenges and problems:**

1. If the customer refreshes the `order-view` page in their account (`my-account`), these strings are generated again and the previous strings are no longer displayed. (Since these strings or random values are generated and cannot be retrieved) If I save them in the database, everything is fine until the customer purchases another copy of this product, but if they purchase another product, only that string is displayed.
2. I want these strings to be stored completely separately for each product in each order. It should be possible to call each of these strings or values and they should not interfere with each other and should be identifiable.
3. I want to learn both the method of storing and the method of calling this method.

**Important note:**

- **These source codes should be executed in `function.php`.**
- **Is the best way to use `get_user_meta`? If this is not a good way, please show me a better solution.**
- *These strings are displayed to the customer as part of the purchased product.*

**After researching, testing, and debugging, I have written the following source code (but I'm not sure if this source code is standard and correct or not. Please help me if there is a bug or if it is not up to standard, so that I can troubleshoot it). It works without any issues, except that if more than one version of a product is purchased, duplicate values are displayed for other versions. However, if only one version of the product is purchased in each order, there is no problem. I had exactly the same issue in my previous question.**

```
function save_random_value($order_id, $product_id, $random_value, $product_name) {
    $random_strings = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $product_name, true);

    if (empty($random_strings)) {
        $random_strings = array();
    }

    if (!isset($random_strings[$order_id])) {
        $random_strings[$order_id] = array();
    }

    $random_strings[$order_id][$product_id] = $random_value;

    update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $product_name, $random_strings);
}


function get_random_value($order_id, $product_id, $product_name) {
    $random_strings = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $product_name, true);

    if (!empty($random_strings) && isset($random_strings[$order_id]) && isset($random_strings[$order_id][$product_id])) {
        return $random_strings[$order_id][$product_id];
    }

    return false;
}



function run_book_func($order_id, $product_id, $type_book) {
    
    if ($type_book == "phys (best)") {
        $book_name = 'dummy_data : phys (best)';
    } else {
        $book_name = 'dummy_data : version (limit)';
    }
    
    $booooooks_item = get_random_value($order_id, $product_id, $product_name);
    if ($booooooks_item) {
        $book_result = $booooooks_item;
    } else {        
        // something...
    
        $book_result = $book_name;
        
        $booooooks_item = $book_result;
        save_random_value($order_id, $product_id, $booooooks_item, $product_name);
        
        return $book_result;
    }
    return $book_result;
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Yes, thank you for your attention. I should have written before the condition.

Comment: Also `$book_result` is not defined in `preg_replace($regex, '', $book_result);`… So it's instead `$book_result = preg_replace($regex, '', $booooooks_item);` and then you can remove unnecessary `$book_result = $booooooks_item;`…

Comment: Dear LoicTheAztec, Thank you for your effort, but I preferred to completely change the method of storing and retrieving values for each order and product and..., as I found it to be flawed and unprofessional. If you would like, please review the new source code that I have added to my question and see if it is proper and standard. Is this method correct and accurate?